# Join по полям, содержащим NULL

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Делаю джойн двух таблиц по равенству нескольких полей

```
ON (t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b and ... t1.z = t2.z)
```

Проблема в том, что в этих полях встречаются NULL-значения, и такие строчки у меня не склеиваются. Мне же нужно, чтобы джойн выполнялся бы так же, как если бы выполнялось равенство NULL=NULL.

Есть ли какой-то устоявшийся способ для такой задачи?

Мне приходит в голову только что-то такое:

```
NVL(t1.a, -1) == NVL(t2.a, -1)
```

для каждого поля, но

1. такое решение кажется не очень красивым;
2. есть сомнения по поводу того, как множество NVL повлияют на производительность.

Comment: В вашем варианте по полям обернутым в `nvl` не будут использоваться индексы. Можно писать так `and(t1.a=t2.a or (t1.a is null and t2.a is null))`. В таком варианте индексы могут быть использованы

Comment: делать "join" по полям содержащим `NULL` - не очень хорошая идея, т.к. в результате вы получите декартово произведение (cartezian product) для всех строк с обеих сторон, содержащих `NULL` в поле `a`

Comment: @lDrakonl На самом деле вряд ли он пойдет по индексу в любом из этих случаев. потому что NULL вообще в индексе отсутствуют и любой поиск NULL пойдет полным сканированием таблицы.

Comment: А вообще сам по себе join по нескольким, тем более более чем по 2-3 полям это очень странно. И скорее всего уже не имеет никакого значения, будете вы использовать nvl или нет, оно не может быть быстрым само по себе (я сильно сомневаюсь, что у вас есть индекс по десятку полей, да даже если есть от него больше вреда чем пользы). А раз так, то nvl уже в принципе ничего не испортит. Лучше бы показали структуру БД которая вынуждает вас делать такой странный join

Comment: "и такие строчки у меня не склеиваются" - какой собственно смысл их склеивать, если значения  по которым они должны склеится не определены. У вас возмозно ошибка при дизайне БД, Дайте жизненый пример - что вы с чем связываете.

Answer (score 1):

делать `join` по полям содержащим `NULL` - не очень хорошая идея, т.к. в результате вы получите декартово произведение ([cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)) для всех строк с обеих сторон, содержащих `NULL` в поле `a`

Пример:

```
create table t1(a int, b int, s varchar2(20));
create table t2(a int, b int, s varchar2(20));

insert into t1 values(1, 1, '1');
insert into t1 values(2, 2, '2');
insert into t1 values(3, 3, '3');
insert into t1 values(NULL, 1, 'NULL.a.1');
insert into t1 values(NULL, 2, 'NULL.a.2');
insert into t1 values(NULL, 3, 'NULL.a.3');
insert into t1 values(NULL, NULL, 'NULL.both.1');
insert into t1 values(NULL, NULL, 'NULL.both.2');

insert into t2 values(1, 1, '1');
insert into t2 values(2, 2, '2');
insert into t2 values(NULL, 1, 'NULL.a.1');
insert into t2 values(NULL, 2, 'NULL.a.2');
insert into t2 values(NULL, NULL, 'NULL.both.1');
insert into t2 values(NULL, NULL, 'NULL.both.2');
```

Запрос:

```
SQL> select * from t1 join t2 on NVL(t1.a, -1) = NVL(t2.a, -1) and NVL(t1.b, -1) = NVL(t2.b, -1);

         A          B S                             A          B S
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         1          1 1                             1          1 1
         2          2 2                             2          2 2
                    1 NULL.a.1                                 1 NULL.a.1
                    2 NULL.a.2                                 2 NULL.a.2
                      NULL.both.1                                NULL.both.2
                      NULL.both.1                                NULL.both.1
                      NULL.both.2                                NULL.both.2
                      NULL.both.2                                NULL.both.1

8 rows selected.
```

По поводу производительности - можно создать `function based index` по `NVL(a, -1)`, но это не решит проблему с декартовым произведением...

Comment: А у него там десяток полей в условиях join судя по всему и null только в некоторых. Так что конкретно об этом можно не беспокоится. гораздо большее беспокойство вызывает сама структура БД

Comment: @Mike, достаточно более одного `NULL` значения в одном и том же столбце в двух таблицах...

Comment: Но тут вопрос исключительно уникальных ключей. Если бы у меня была бы подобная структура я бы позаботился что бы запись из всех NULL могла быть только одна либо такой записи в принципе не могло быть. Так что в таком контексте NULL можно рассматривать как обычное значение, а не как что то особенное. тем более что точно такое же декартово произведение можно получить и без всяких NULL сделав например 2 записи (1,1). И дубль (1,1) ничем не отличается от дубля (NULL,NULL)

Comment: @Mike, c вашим утверждением трудно согласиться, т.к. `NULL != NULL` а `1 == 1`, поэтому и придумали все эти `IS NULL`, `NVL`, `COALESCE`, etc. Я  бы перевел `NULL` как "неопределенность" - сравнивать неопределенности можно только с кучей оговорок, а `JOIN` использует сравнение... Поэтому данный "дизайн" может рассыпаться в любой момент. Как вы, например, предлагаете __эффективно__ проверять, что в столбце не больше одного значения `NULL`?

Comment: Сделать уникальный функциональный индекс на основе того же самого NVL. заодно join по NVL начнет работать по этому индексу

Comment: @Mike, да, я и забыл, что уже написал об этом в своем ответе... Но это таааак коряво....

Comment: ну не знаю, если уж такова задача. я уже даже придумал хороший пример. Хранение ФИО (ну если предположить что у нам нужна уникальность по ФИО) отчества у многих народов нет. у некоторых нет фамилий. NULL будет обозначать именно то, что требуется - отсутствие значения

Comment: @Mike, `уникальность по ФИО` - хммм... я знаю фирмы в которых работают по 5-7 `Peter Müller`... ;-) И делать `JOIN` по ФИО - это тупиковый путь...

Answer (score 1):

Мне приходит в голову такая конструкция:

```
on a.x is null and b.x is null or a.x = b.x
```